# Unable to debug Windows Phone apps when installed from the Store

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xna, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

I develop a Windows Phone app. Publish it to the Store (BETA or LIVE). I install the app from the store (to test) to my WP 8.1 device. Now having done this, anytime I try to debug the app (Run to DEVICE) I get the famous:

`"A specified communication resource (port) is already in use by another application."`

[image]

I can bypass this error and debug when I change my assembly's GUID to NOT match with the App in the store. But then, obviously, I cannot test the store functionality (listing the in-app products and such).

Is there any workaround / solution for this?

VS2013 Ultimate, WP8.1, XNA project on Win8.1 lastest updates.

Comment: I often get this when I debug any WP8 App. Usually it helps to just wait half a minute or so, and attempt to start debugging again.

Comment: Thanks, Bjarke, but this one is literally related to the GUID of the project. If the GUID of the project I am trying to debug is the same as the GUID of the application I installed form the store, I get this error.

Comment: Oh, yeah that makes sense. In that case, I'd suggest either changing the GUID while developing (and remember to change back when publishing), or uninstall the one from the store.

Comment: Uninstalling doesn't help (unless there is some other way to totally clean the app from the phone other than standard uninstall) and when I change the GUID I can no longer test STORE functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
  verifiy you App Manifest File 4 WP8 (XAML) in VS 
  the GUID parameter must be look like this
```

see section "Changes in the upgraded app manifest file" & find PublisherID parameter value 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx

Regards !

AP

Comment: My project is not really WP8 project. Since it's an XNA game, it's in fact WP7 project, but running in VS2013, it's actually something in between :D However, PublisherID doesn't work - can't even compile with that...